# having multiple forms on same php page

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to create a php page where

1. Initially, there are two textboxes, and a submit button called
   submit
2. On clicking the submit button, it shows a table containing
   checkboxes, and a submit button called submit2
3. On checking a few checkboxes, and clicking the submit button called
   submit2, I would like to get all the checkboxes that were checked.

This is my attempt for the above. Steps 1 and 2 work fine, however, I'm not able to proceed with Step 3.

PS : I require all three steps to be on the same page, without jumping pages everytime there is a new submit button. Also, I'm using GET and not POST.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="self.php" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $a=count($array1);
    echo "<table width=100% border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><th>Array1</th><th>Array2</th><th>Checkboxes</th></tr>";

    for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$array1[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$array1[$i]."</td>";
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="" id="checkbox"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo "</table>";

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit2">';
}

if(isset($_GET['submit2']))
{
    echo "pressed the second submit button";
}
?>
```

Comment: The second lot doesn't have a form around the input fields. Add that and it should work fine. The submit button submits the form in which is is embedded. It also appears outside the body/html tags which will also cause problems.

Comment: Why are you using `$_GET`?

Comment: @Brian, GET or POST would do. Take that back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap php code into `<form>` tag like

```
echo '<form action="self.php" method="get">';
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    $a=count($array1);
    echo "<table width=100% border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><th>Array1</th><th>Array2</th><th>Checkboxes</th></tr>";

    for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$array1[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$array1[$i]."</td>";
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="" id="checkbox"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo "</table>";

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit2">';
}
echo '</form>';
```

Also, if you need to pass `name` and `email` variables from Step 1 to Step 3, add

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='{$_GET['name']}'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='email' value='{$_GET['email']}'>";
```

inside `if(isset($_GET['name']))`